# Resource handler returned message: "No integration defined for method (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I want to import a YAML file into API GateWay.
Whenever I do so I get the following error

> Resource handler returned message: "No integration defined for method (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400

I use the following code to import the YAML file

```js
const integration = new LambdaIntegration(hello)

const api = new SpecRestApi(this, 'books-api', {
  apiDefinition: ApiDefinition.fromAsset('apiTrial.yaml')
});

const booksResource = api.root.addResource('books')
booksResource.addMethod('GET', integration);

});
```

and my current yaml file is:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: "MyFirstAPI"
  version: "1.0.0"
  contact:
    name: Karim Fayed
    email: contact@example.com
    url: https://example.com/
tags:
  - name: Metadata
    description: Metadata related requests
servers:
- url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5"
paths:
  /:
    get:
      operationId: getMetadata
      summary: Get metadata from the root of the API
      tags: [ 'Metadata for root' ]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
  /weather:
    get:
      operationId: "getMetadata"
      summary: "Get metadata from weather API"
      tags: ["metadata data for wather"]
      responses:
       200:
        description: successful operation
       400:
        description: Invalid id supplied
       404:
        description: Contact not found
       500:
        description: Server error
```

As you can see I already have a response for code 400 so why would the error keep showing up?

Comment: [The solution could be here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html), [Or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087890/no-integration-defined-for-method-choose-a-stage-where-your-api-will-be-deploy)

Comment: Thank you for your help, the link to the other stack overflow question was the answer

Comment: Write the answer please to close this question.