# No integration defined for method (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-sam

Hi Aws Cloudformation Guys!

I am facing the below error when trying to **sam deploy** my api gateways.
I have my api gateway endpoint definitions as **openapi** yaml (*api.yaml*) file and attach it to the api gateway definition in **template.yaml** in **DefinitionBody** Attribute.

```
Resource handler returned message: "No integration defined for method       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
(Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID:                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
84d74c87-d8b4-476f-a717-f8a885f78f05)" (RequestToken:                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
295d3709-e28c-4254-08b1-317f56af6532, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

What must I be missing?

- I have only 1 api definition in api.yaml file. No unused api in yaml.
- I Have only 1 lambda function defined in template.yaml

I referred to [No integration defined for method - Choose a stage where your API will be deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087890/no-integration-defined-for-method-choose-a-stage-where-your-api-will-be-deploy) , before posting this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know why without seeing the template.yaml file. It would be helpful if you could edit the question with parts of the template.

However what the error generally means is that the integration between the API Gateway and the Lambda function might be missing. The previous question you mentioned reflects the same. There might be a API method in the API Gateway definition that is missing the link to the lambda function.